# How to standardise font-sizes across different font-family

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-size

I am using Oswald (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oswald) and Bebas Neue (http://dharmatype.com/dharma-type/bebas-neue.html) on my website.

I am loading both via `font-face` (Oswald via Google Web Fonts, but it's the same process).

However, the fonts themselves appear with dramatically different heights when using the same font-size definition (e.g. `font-size:14px` renders two very different sizes).

I need them to render the same size for the page to work.

Two questions: i) what is causing this difference, and ii) what can be done to fix it? Preferably with IE8 compliance.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's impossible because If you had been created a font, you know that there's a reserved space for each character and you're able to create the character in any size in that space.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: Glyphs in a font are positioned on a canvas. They need whitespace around to be positioned to each other. The amount of white differs. One of the reasons is the ratio between x-height to size of ascenders (bdfhklt) and descenders (gjqpy). If a font has relative small x-height (large (as/de)cenders), than there is more white around a glyph than with a font that has relative big x-height. There are more variables that influence the amount of white. capital/lowercase ratio and font weight.

Answer 2: Nothing is broken. You can use css and set font-size relatively and correct the size of a text.

[image: x-height and capital height]

*You can scroll the image to the edge of your browser window to check where the glyphs align.*

Top: No adjustment

Middle: Same x-height. This looks good!

Bottom: Same capital height. This is what you need since one of your fonts is all capitals.

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        p
        {
            border: 1px solid red;
            line-height: 1EM;
            font-size: 600%;
            margin: 0 0 0.1EM 0;
        }

        .arial { font-family: 'Arial'; }
        .times { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; }

        .times_same_x_height { font-size:116%; }
        .times_same_capital_height { font-size:108%; }        

        .font_stack { font-family: "Does not exist", serif; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>
        <span class="arial">xH</span>
        <span class="times">xH</span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="arial">xH</span>
        <span class="times times_same_x_height">xH</span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span class="arial">xH</span>
        <span class="times times_same_capital_height">xH</span>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Note 0: *If it looks right, it is right.* So don't use x-height and be done with it. Sometimes a clear difference in size will make a font combination more harmonious. Use your eyes (and brain).

Note 1: I placed text in the same paragraph. I did it because it aligns the baseline. But it's more likely that your text elements are separated form each other. Define the right  `line-height` and `margin` to position. Use relative values. And sometimes a little baseline shift: `.shift { top: -.01EM; position:relative; }`

Note 2: If your font does not exist. The font_stack will use the next best font. Realize that your fine typography applies to all fonts in the stack!

Tip: If you want to change the weight of a font slightly. You can make the color just a little lighter. Eg. from black to very dark gray. This will make it look less bold.

Bonus: IE will comply.

Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The sizes of characters (relative to font size) depend on the decisions of the font designer. This is basically just something that you need to take into account when choosing font combinations. As a rule, fonts don’t mix well, unless designed to.

The [`font-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust) property was intended to address this problem. But it is supported by Firefox only, and in a broken way.